# Permanently deleted files from the desktop (OneDrive cloud)

Tags: windows, backup, filesystems, onedrive

The most terrible problem of every person or teenager has arisen. I decided to clean the computer, as I noticed that the "C" disk was clogged. Logged into the WizTree app. I scanned it, saw where it was most busy, and began deleting files. And accidentally deleted the OneDrive folder that had the Desktop folder in it. Everything you need has been deleted. In particular, the folder with all the photos of my mom, where there were a lot of photos, about 10 GB for sure.

Scoured the entire Internet, how to recover deleted files. Nothing helps, Recuva sees nothing at all. What can be done at all in this situation?

Comment: One Drive does warn you that deleting in one location deletes everywhere. Hard lesson learned.

Comment: Log into ondrive from the browser and look if the files are still there. You may have only deleted the files keept locally on the disk but not the online version.